# фильтр по возрасту

Tags: php, mysql

Есть поле формат date 0000-00-00 с датами рождения.
Как отфильтровать данные селектом например  >55 лет и <23 лет

Решил таким образом

```
$god передается через get 
if ($god == "23")   {$znak = '<=23';} else {$znak = '>55'; }
Запрос такой "YEAR(NOW())- YEAR(denrogdeniya)$znak";
```

А теперь как выбрать всех тех кому от 23 лет до 55

Answer (score 1):

ну вы же знаете какой год должен быть если человеку 23 года например и вот запрос

php

```
`$today = date("m/d/y");
```

sql

```
Select * FROM table WHERE DateDiff(date,$today)<23   //23 года
Select * FROM table WHERE DateDiff(date,$today)>55   //55 лет
```

Comment: А если на дворе наступит 2017 год?

Comment: До 2017 ещё дожить надо. А вообще отнимаете от 2017 года 23 получаете 1994. Значить условие в 2017 году будет < 1/1/1994. Можно поступить по другому, если в базе есть арифметика с датами. текущая_дата between дата_рождения + 23года and дата_рождения + 55лет. Но первый вариант проще, так как не требует никаких дополнительных вычислений для каждой записи

Comment: тогда  совместим с пхп условие определять динамически на пхп и передавать в   Sql 

добавил в ответ.

Comment: Решил таким образом
$god передается через get 
if ($god == "23")   {$znak = '<=23';} else {$znak = '>55'; }
Запрос такой "YEAR(NOW())- YEAR(denrogdeniya)$znak";
А теперь как выбрать всех тех кому от 23 лет до 55

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year
FROM
table_name
WHERE
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(CURDATE())-55) AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-23);
```